# Insert hyperlink in Google Calendar's description field

Tags: google-calendar

I need to insert a link in my Google Calendar, but when I write out the description field with `https://www.google.com/`, it's just normal text.

I've tried to write `<a href="https://www.google.com/">link</a>` but it doesn't work. It's always interpreted just as simple text.

Comment: Why do you expect to insert working hyperlinks in the description? Did you see this functionality elsewhere?

Comment: I expect it, because its very usefull to have links in description, isnt it? :) And from my phone I see these links as clickable (standart google app), when I share calendar in HTML format, other user see my links clickable as well. But I cant (direct in my calendaer).

Comment: yah it was totally working a while ago and now it's not :((( I have a social site and it made it super easy to sell tickets when it worked.

Comment: Are there any updates regarding this issue? I'm facing the same problem. Is there a possibility to set the content type of the description file to say HTML?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, by using the HTML code `<a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>`. I have a Google calendar set up for a club, if you are in edit mode, it appears as text, if you are not in edit mode , ie log out of your Google mail, than look at your calendar, the link will work. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can I see somehow these clickable links without logout?

Comment: Nope - HTML code works no more, save for Firefox. Seems to be working intermittently on IE8, not on Chrome (curious because it's Google), Opera nor Safari. Any new reason for this? Clients complained about it now for several days.

Comment: Your solution works now - IE9, Chrome, Firefox , put the "h ref link" in the description, but I had to leave off the "" marks?? then use another browser to view the calendar, click on the event, click on the link

Comment: Perhaps you can add the `URL` as well?

Comment: I can confirm this works as of 2014-07-08.

Comment: Working in Feb 2020

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The input is simply interpreted as plain text. Now, the URLs *can* become click-able in a different client that converts plain text URLs to hyperlinks, but that is outside of Google Calendar's control.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is insert the link without any HTML coding (E.g. just, http://google.com), saved the event, and although it is not a live link on my calendar when I view it on my computer, it is live when viewed on the standard calendar app on my Android smartphone.  I've found this to be very handy.

I have not found a way to make it live on the computer when I am signed in, but I'm not sure how such an even would appear to other's viewing my calendar; perhaps it would be clickable for them.

**Snarky note:**  Notice how http://google.com automatically becomes a live link in this response?  I wonder why it can't just be that simple in Google Calendar?  Even if they'd just add a box when you schedule an event that's entitled URL, it seems it would be a pretty simple thing.  I was also able to bold "Snarky Note" with simple HTML, so it isn't like Google is unfamiliar with its use.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to type the whole URL. If I put link code in HTML it doesn't work.

So for example, in the description if I want a link, I simply put the URL: `http://www.example.com`. The calendar automatically makes it a link. No coding.
Some of my URLs are long and ugly.

It's not pretty but it's a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Placing a full URL in the calendar event description field still does not result in an active link on the published calendar (unless you use a browser/system that automatically activates links); however, the `more details` link that appears in the published event description does, in fact, display the active link.

While not elegant, you can place a note next to the URL that directs users to `click 'more details...' to activate link`

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been kicking around since at least 2009. There always seem to be some folks who can get it to work, and some who cannot. It certainly does not work for me. The best work around I have found is that in Chrome I can triple click the unlinked link, right click and choose Open URL from the pop-up menu. Sort of like a web page from a pre-technological society, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the (map) element within Google Calendar

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;q=Sangerville%20Fire%20Department" class="menu-link" target="_blank">map</a>
```

I was able to replace the data within the `""` with my YouTube Video link

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8O55GUQVlR0
```

and changed the word *map* to *video*.

I tried to duplicate this script by hand, however I have often found that for some reason it is just not the same.

Replace that link which is between the `""` and replace its title *map* with your wording.

Comment: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8O55GUQVlR0" class="menu-link" target="_blank">Video</a>

Comment: This works with Google Drive "Shared" documents and other links as well.

Answer (score -3):

=hyperlink(ʺurl”;ʺname of your linkʺ)

Example:
=hyperlink(ʺhttp://www.yahoo.comʺ;ʺClick here to go to yahooʺ)

Comment: That's for Google Spreadsheets. This is asking about Google Calendar.