# Inserting a "tel:" hyperlink in Google Calendar description

Tags: google-calendar

This question is an extension of [this existing question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27715/insert-hyperlink-in-google-calendars-description-field).

I'm able to add any website link as a hyperlink in Google Calendar,
but when I try to add a hyperlink that's not a website link, it doesn't show up as a hyperlink, but the whole a HREF HTML code is seen in the calendar invites.

`mobile callers, tap the link for your phone
"<"a href="tel:xxx.xxx.xxxx,,confCode#,,%23">Android / iPhone / Windows Phone`

There was a "BT MeetMe" plugin in my Outlook that used to add this hyperlink to my Outlook calendar invites. I'm trying to replicate the same in Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for your question. It's not exactly a straight-forward click-to-call link per se, but it works perfectly.

1. Go to your settings in the upper right-hand portion of your calendar page.
2. Click on the "Get Add-ons" link. This opens a secondary window so have your popups open for the app.

[image: Screenshot of the Get Add-ons function in Google Calendar]
3. There will be 4-5 different integrations like RingCentral, UberConference, GoToMeeting, etc. Choose the one you're most comfortable with, although they all work pretty similar, the point is they work.

4. Create your event. and when you see the section "Add Conferencing" select your integration and follow the instructions. The result will be a click-to-call Number in the Info section that your client can click and if their device is set-up for it, will call you.
   [image: Screenshot of RingCentral "click-to-call" function in Google Calendar Event Creation]

This option should work perfectly fine for you.
Best of luck!